# Unable to find a workflow for class "FooBundle\Entity\Document" when that class have two workflows

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-workflows

Exception error says that cant find a class that exists and it is used in the project. Here the WF configuration:

### Workflow configuration:

```
first_workflow_name:
    type: 'workflow'
    supports:
        - FooBundle\Entity\Document
    marking_store:
        type: 'multiple_state'
        arguments:
            - 'currentState'

second_workflow_name:
    type: 'workflow'
    supports:
        - FooBundle\Entity\Document
    marking_store:
        type: 'multiple_state'
        arguments:
            - 'currentState'
```

and here the logged exception:

### Logged Exception:

> [2018-09-07 09:11:38] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Workflow\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "Unable
>   to find a workflow for class "FooBundle\Entity\Document"."

### Controller

```
public function getFooAction(
    $id,
    Registry $workflows
) {
    $document = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('FooBundle:Document')
        ->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

    if (!$document) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No Document found for id '.$id
        );
    }

    $w = $workflows->get($document, 'second_workflow_name');
}
```

Comment: May be your `namespace` incorrect?

Comment: Nope @ImanaliMamadiev . With one workflow it works. With two workflow `$workflows->get($document)` require the workflow name. Fixing the name this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In your twig you write:

```
workflow_can(you_variable,'second_workflow_name','arguments')
```

instead of:

```
workflow_can(you_variable,'arguments','second_workflow_name')
```